# Do the serial voting scripts take into account user age and frequency of posts?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

We have a user on Retrocomputing who has joined the site yesterday and has posted a large number of answers (11) in a short period of time (2 hours).  I've reviewed some of their posts in the First Posts and Late Answers review queue, upvoting those I've found are useful and detailed (many of them).  I haven't cast that many votes today, and I'm afraid the serial voting script will think this is voting fraud.

The FAQ Q&A pair ([What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/242209)) does not go into detail about this scenario.  I didn't really notice this until after the fact, since I mainly look at the post content rather than the user when going through the review queues.  Am I at risk of (or committing) voting fraud here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not going to go into detail about it either; the high-level description is "statistical anomalies" and that'll have to suffice.

As a general rule, don't worry about the voting scripts. They're *extremely* conservative; if you get caught by them, you're probably doing something that very few people do. If, some strange day, that happens a few times... No big deal; if you're running into it *every* day, you might wanna ask yourself what you're doing.

(I had someone tell me once that his preferred method of voting was to save up every post he saw that needed to be voted on over the course of a day, sort them by author and vote type, and then vote on them as fast as he possibly could. I don't know that I believe him, but if you ever get it in your head to do something like that... Don't.)